# Laravel order table by different table column

Tags: php, sql, laravel, select, eloquent

So i have the table Threads and the table Comments, I want to sort threads by the last comment inserted in something like comments.created_at, how I do this?

```
    $threads = Thread::where('subboaId', $id)
           ->orderBy('comments.created_at', 'desc')
           ->get();
```

tried this but not working maybe I have to join them or something

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? 4.x or 5.x?

Answer (score 3):

Use whereHas function (https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships) :

First you must add relationship at your Thread model :

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany( Comment::class );
}
```

And then you can use it at your controller like this :

```
$threads = Thread::where('subboaId', $id)->whereHas( 'comments', function( $query ){
    $query->orderBy( 'created_at', 'desc' );
} )->get();
```

Hope it's helps.

Comment: With this only threads with comments are shown, also it's ordered by created_at from threads, it's ignoring comments :S

Comment: Yes it's only show thread with comments because you ordering rows based on comments, what do you want with thread that have no comments? @Sociopath

Comment: If thread has no comments I want to compare his created_at with comment created_at and see who should stay on top

Comment: @Sociopath, the better way to do that is always update thread's updated_at when there is new comment, so you just need to order it by thread's updated_at

Answer (score 0):

Join them and Try this one,

```
    $threads = Thread::join('comments', 'comments.id', '=', 'threads.comment_id')
                ->where('threads.subboaId', $id)
                ->orderBy('comments.created_at', 'desc')
                ->get();
```

I hope this will help/lead you.